# C# Messaging implementation similar to Apache Camel

Tags: apache, c#-3.0, esb

Does anybody know if their is a open or even closed source c# messaging framework, perhaps based on wcf, which is similar in nature to Apache Cambel.

I like Camel as it implemented a nice lightweight modern messageing framework based on the Enterprise Integration patterns by Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf. Pretty much everything I need for my product, many different types of routing, etc. Plenty of goodness really.

The problem I have with using WCF is so granular, whereas this wee framework has everything I need to message packets, has a nice dsl, partly based on xpath predicates, and it's a perfect fit. It would be cool if their was some kind of wcf implementation of the book, perhaps in c# but I can't find anything suitable.

I don't know if I want to go down a mixed programming path at the mo, although I suppose you could implement a straight i/o interface to Camel, say via web services.

Any ideas. 
Bob.

Comment: I'm also looking for a messaging bus that doesn't implement a copyleft licence.

Comment: Similar to Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you might want to check out [Mass Transit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/). I have no experience with it; just heard about it on a podcast.

Comment: Hi TrueWill, 
Its similar to what i'm looking for, but it's really not a production stage.

Comment: Also it seems to be very granular, working from the YAGNI principle, which will probably make it unusable in most cases.